# UIProgressView setProgress

Tags: ios, swift

I am attempting to implement a UIProgress view. I run the function setProgress each time the end of an iteration is performed in a for loop. The progress is set like this:

```
let progress: Float = Float(i + 1) / Float(list.count)
```

And the progress function looks like this:

```
progressView.setProgress(progress, animated: true)
```

Yet, the progress bar is not updated on each loop. Why is this?

Comment: can you share the loop func?

Comment: `for i in 0...list.count - 1{`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should do it in your main queue with the async method

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    progressView.setProgress(progress, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: For some reason Apple decided to have some operations relegated to only working in the main thread. Many of these are human interface (view) oriented but some are not.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run your loop in a background thread and use the main thread only to update the UI, the progress of the progressView in your case.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0) {
    for i in 0...list.count - 1 {
        // Do your work here
        // ...
        // ...

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            progressView.setProgress(progress, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```